# Annotation and Defining bean in Spring xml

Tags: spring

In any case do we need to define the spring bean as annotation as well as in spring xml.

If no, which one is more maintainable and have more advantages.

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to do both. It is a case of one or the other.

I personally prefer having an xml file, as it allows me to see all of the resources I am wiring in one place, but it comes down to a matter of opinion.

Comment: Is there will be any performance difference? some says annotation is pretty faster than xml configuration. is that true?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest with you. Here is a helpful article that seems to suggest a nice midway point, where you still have a list of all of the elements used, but they are loaded with annotations.
[link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)